# Run tasks in a particular instance ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a setup of 8 tasks and I want

To run 6 tasks in `instance 1` and 2 other services in `instance 2`

How do I achieve this setup? Does ECS supports this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do some managmanet of task placement using [ECS task placement constraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html). For example, you could use `instance-type` constrain if the two instances have different types.